# How To Convert Blend Format Into OBJ

Tags: mesh

How do I convert my blender file into OBJ format? Is there a specific software I need? Or is there a blender add on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No addons needed, just go to *File > Export > Wavefront OBJ*

You can also Import OBJ files from *File > Import > Wavefront OBJ*

[From the Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_obj.html?highlight=obj#wavefront-obj)